# How to modify html string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to use jQuery to modify the HTML template.

For example:

```
var d = '<div class="a"><div class="b"></div><div class="c"></div></div>';

var html = $(d).find(".b").html("BBBBB");

console.log(d);   // I want to get the new html
```

In above, I want to get

`'<div class="a"><div class="b">BBBBB</div><div class="c"></div></div>'`

How can implement the case？ Please suggest.

Comment: Try `console.log(html)`

Comment: why not directly use `$('.b').html("BBBBB")`

Comment: `d` is a variable and not DOM element. So it has no .html() method on it. What you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Because html string in a variable, not in brower document, I just can get it by `find`. @Aditya

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here is the code:

```
var d = '<div class="a"><div class="b"></div><div class="c"></div></div>';

var html = $(d).find(".b").html("BBBBB").end()[0].outerHTML;

console.log(html);
```

Note the key is to use `.end()`, which will pop off the context of `<div class="b">` created by the `.find()` operation and return you to just `$(d)`, which then allows you to get the full HTML using `.outerHTML` on the raw DOM node.

Comment: This is the correct answer and by far the best way to achieve it, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = '<div class="a"><div class="b"></div><div class="c"></div></div>';

$('.a').find(".b").html("BBBBB");
var newD = $('.a').parent().html();

console.log(newD);
```

You are writing into a DOM element not a variable. You need the again fetch the modified DOM element.